# Unserializing value from Wikipedia API fails

Tags: php, serialization

I'm trying to get data from Wikipedia, however unserialization fails every time.

Sample query should get section 20 from the Honda Civic page:

```
<?php
exec("curl -s 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=php&page=Honda_Civic&prop=text&section=20'", $output);

$value = "";
$first = true;
foreach ($output as $line) {
   if ($first) {
      $first = false;
   } else {
      $value .= "\n";
   }

   $value .= $line;
}

print("~~~\n");
print($value);
print("\n~~~\n");
print(unserialize($value));
print("~~~\n");
```

Results in:

```
~~~
a:1:{s:5:"parse";a:2:{s:5:"title";s:11:"Honda Civic";s:4:"text";a:1:{s:1:"*";s:1476:"<h4><span class="editsection">[<a href="/w/index.php?title=Honda_Civic&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: WTCC">edit</a>]</span> <span class="mw-headline" id="WTCC">WTCC</span></h4>
<p>Honda announced to enter the 2012 <a href="/wiki/World_Touring_Car_Championship" title="World Touring Car Championship">World Touring Car Championship</a> (WTCC) with a racer built on the 2012 Euro Civic 5 door hatchback. The car is powered by a 1.6-liter turbocharged engine, developed by Honda R&amp;D, and will race later in Japan, China and Macau before a two car team join the 2013 championship racing.<sup id="cite_ref-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-1"><span>[</span>1<span>]</span></a></sup><sup id="cite_ref-2" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-2"><span>[</span>2<span>]</span></a></sup><br />
<strong class="error">Cite error: There are <code>&lt;ref&gt;</code> tags on this page, but the references will not show without a <code>{{Reflist}}</code> template or a <code>&lt;references /&gt;</code> tag (see the <a href="/wiki/Help:Cite_errors/Cite_error_refs_without_references" title="Help:Cite errors/Cite error refs without references">help page</a>).</strong></p>


<!--
NewPP limit report
Preprocessor visited node count: 146/1000000
Preprocessor generated node count: 1599/1500000
Post‐expand include size: 3103/2048000 bytes
Template argument size: 1880/2048000 bytes
Highest expansion depth: 12/40
Expensive parser function count: 0/500
-->
";}}}
~~~
~~~
```

Yeah, there are "cite errors" but the data should still unserialize. Any idea what's going on here?

If I run it from within my real script (versus the simplified script given here), I get the same output but also the following potentially useful information:

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 1583 of 1587 bytes
```

Comment: Try using `print_r` or `var_dump` instead of `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the data through curl and the shell and it gets modified by that in a way that it destroys the data.

Instead fetch the data in a manner that does not break it and you should be fine.

Example Code:

```
$url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=php&page=Honda_Civic&prop=text&section=20';

$buffer = file_get_contents($url);

$test = unserialize($buffer);

var_dump($test);
```

Result:

```
array(1) {
  'parse' =>
  array(2) {
    'title' =>
    string(11) "Honda Civic"
    'text' =>
    array(1) {
      '*' =>
      string(1476) "<h4><span class="editsection">[<a href="/w/index.php?title=Honda_Civic&amp;action=edit&amp;section=1" title="Edit section: WTCC">edit</a>]</span> <span class="mw-headline" id="WTCC">WTCC</span></h4>\n<p>Honda announced to enter the 2012 <a href="/wiki/World_Touring_Car_Championship" title="World Touring Car Championship">World Touring Car Championship</a> (WTCC) with a racer built on the 2012 Euro Civic 5 door hatchback. The car is powered by a 1.6-liter turbocharged engine, developed by Honda R&amp;D, and "...
    }
  }
}
```

---

So why do you get an error on the one computer but not on the other. And what does this error:

> ```
> unserialize(): Error at offset 1583 of 1587 bytes
> ```

mean? When PHP unserialzes a string it parses it based on it's own format. That format makes it expect various stuff at various offsets. For example strings are enclosed into double-quotes and also prefixed with their length in bytes. So the parser moves on to the end of the string based on the length given and checks if at that calculated offset it is finding the `"` double quote. In your case probably exactly the case with offset 1583 but not finding it.

This most likely is the problem when a different character encoding has a different byte-length for strings. For example just in the part at the end that you've put into your question:

```
Preprocessor generated node count: 1599/1500000
Post‐expand include size: 3103/2048000 bytes
Template argument size: 1880/2048000 bytes
```

The hyphen in *`Post‐expand`* is actually [Unicode Character 'HYPHEN' (U+2010)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2010/index.htm). It consumes three bytes in the serialized string.

However if you mangle the output through the shell, this can be converted into a different encoding used in the shell, so the byte-length is only one byte for the dash - because it was converted into `-` (minus-sign, ASCII hyphen) which consumes one byte.

On another system STDIO might not mangle the encoding because it is in UTF-8 and therefore it does not break.

Another workaround can be to tell the curl commandline tool to write into a temporary file and then load that temporary file with `file_get_contents`.